# VBA code not sorting by CASE - also can't apply to multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT: I just noticed the VBA script isn't working at all, it looks like it is just sorting by the first column as I am getting some funny results :S?

I am using the following VBA to sort by all columns on the sheet.

```
Sub SortVariableColumns()
Dim strLastCol As String
Dim lngLastCol As Long

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet

With ActiveSheet
lngLastCol = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
strLastCol = Split(sht.Cells(1, lngLastCol).Address, "$")(1)

sht.Columns("A:" & strLastCol).Select
sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal ', Header:=xlYes
End With
With sht.Sort
.SetRange Columns("A:" & strLastCol)
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = True
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

However, it isn't matching case for some reason. The sort works for everything but the case of the words.

Also, is there anyway to make this then move onto the next sheet (i.e. if I selected activeworksheets) - I tried using

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
```

this but kept failing, I guess it has something to do with having to reset the IngLastCOl/StrLastCol holding from the first part of the VBA?

Many thanks.

Comment: `Set sht = ActiveSheet` What's with this? `With ActiveSheet` if you are setting the sheet, then use the reference object variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@boncoDigo

I think I mispasted the code - the code wasn't actually failing on anything related to that! Sorry.

---

This can now be closed. I have worked out how to do it.

For those interested, this is the code that I used (can be easily amended to loop through sheets):

Sub SortVariableColumns()

Dim finalcolumn As Integer
Dim FinalRow As Integer

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
With ActiveSheet

finalcolumn = Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
FinalRow = Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For N = 1 To finalcolumn Step 1

```
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(2, N), Cells(FinalRow, N)), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Next N
End With
With sht.Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, finalcolumn))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = True
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

What's with this as well?

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
```

Where have you defined `ws` variable? I am not suprised if this code fails at every line or never run at all. These are some fundamental issues.